# Audiokit AKFFTTap generate array of 0 in offline rendering mode

Tags: ios, swift, macos, fft, audiokit

I'm trying to use Audiokit and its AKFFTap to get the fft data of an audiofile.

I manage to get them in real time processing but as soos as I do it in offline rendering mode the generated data are 0.

So I was wondering if it was possible to get it with the offline rendering mode?

Here is the code I use:

```
class OfflineProcessingClass {

  var tracker: AKFrequencyTracker!
  var fftTap: AKFFTTap!

  // ....

  private func process(audioFile: AKAudioFile) throws {
    // Make connection
    let player = try AKAudioPlayer(file: audioFile)
    tracker = AKFrequencyTracker(player)
    fftTap = AKFFTTap(tracker)
    AudioKit.output = tracker

    // Setup offline rendering mode
    let timeIntervalInSeconds: TimeInterval = 0.1
    let sampleInterval = Int(floor(timeIntervalInSeconds * audioFile.sampleRate))

     try AudioKit.engine.enableManualRenderingMode(
      .offline,
      format: audioFile.fileFormat,
      maximumFrameCount: AVAudioFrameCount(sampleInterval)
    )

    // Setup buffer
    let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(
      pcmFormat: AudioKit.engine.manualRenderingFormat,
      frameCapacity: AudioKit.engine.manualRenderingMaximumFrameCount
    )

    // Start processing
    try AudioKit.start()
    player.start()

    // Read file offline
    while AudioKit.engine.manualRenderingSampleTime < audioFile.length {
      let frameCount = audioFile.length - manualRenderingSampleTime
      let framesToRender = min(AVAudioFrameCount(frameCount), buffer.frameCapacity)

      try! AudioKit.engine.renderOffline(framesToRender, to: buffer)

      // track is good
      print("\(tracker.amplitude) dB - \(tracker!.frequency) Hz")

      // Array of 0
      print(fftTap.fftData) /////////////// <====== Error is here
    }

    // End processing
    player.stop()
    AudioKit.engine.stop()
  }

}
```

Do you see something wrong in this code?

Comment: Yeah, I would have thought taps work in offline rendering. Looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `handleTapBlock` in `BaseTap` does a dispatch async on the main queue. That means, since you're occupying the main queue in your `for` loop, the `BaseTap` will never have the opportunity to get any callbacks. You'll need to relinquish the main queue for that to work.